# How do I split the full dataset to training and test datasets by 50-50

Tags: r, database, split, dataset

I've been going crazy looking for this all over the place. Most splits that I've found is ''if you want to split the X variable in the dataset''. No, I need to split the entire dataset, the full totality of it, to training and test by 50-50.
Please help, I'm new to this and somehow stumbling my way through it.

Let's say that the dataset is named DATASET. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## data.table method

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DATASET)

DATASET[, test := sample(0:1, nrow(DATASET), replace = T, prob = c(0.5,0.5))]

DATASET_1 <- split(DATASET, 'test')
```

## Base R method

```
DATASET$test <- sample(0:1, nrow(DATASET), replace = T, prob = c(0.5,0.5))

DATASET_1 <- split(DATASET, DATASET$test)
```

Comment: For some reason I don't have data.table even offered in my packages

Comment: Perhaps you have not installed it. Try `install.packages('data.table')`. Or try the base R method (do not require any packages installed)

Comment: Alright, did so but nothing happens. I don't even get an error, R just reads what I wrote in the code and that is it.
No, I'm an idiot. It works now that I just enter DATASET_1, thanks :)
Now I just need to figure out how to understand it xD

Comment: After running the solution you should end up with a new object: `DATASET_1`. This is a list of 2 dataframes. One for training, the other for test.

Comment: One last question, sorry. If I need to build a machine learning module on the training dataset, based on this split, how do I select the training dataset?

Comment: To select training set from the list: `DATASET_1[['0']]`. Or from the original dataframe: `DATASET[DATASET$test == 0, ]`

Answer (score 1):

here is another way:

```
DATASET[, train:=sample(1:.N)<.N/2]
```

Comment: Succinct. Thumbed up